# Covering any surface with helix-shaped curves

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I have a question about the feasability of an idea. 
I have a surface (which can be parametrized or defined implicitly by an equation F(x,y,z) = 0) and I want to draw some helix that fit the surface, litterally helix on the surface.
What would be the process to achieve that ?
I have a basic idea ,which is inspired from ray marching methods,  : I have my surface (which have a finite area) then I 'draw' a big helix curve around it and I decrease the radius of the helix. If the helix intersect the surface then I save that point, and finally I would obtain the set of points that draw an helix on the surface...
Feel free to ask me questions about the problem.
Thank you for your attention.
thomas

Comment: Take a look at [this project](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/zippables/).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to understand "drawing a helix curve" on a surface. By the way, I am not sure that you use the proper term, as a helix is a spring-like curve and is not flat at all. I will instead assume some planar curve described by an implicit `C(x,y)=0` or parametric `x=Xc(t),y=Yc(t)` representation.

One approach is by using a `(u,v)` parameterization of the surface, as used in texture mapping, `x=Xs(u,v), y=Ys(u, v), z=Zs(u, v)`. For example, for a sphere `(u,v)` could correspond to the angle coordinates in the spherical system. In this case, it suffices to map `x=u, y=v` and there will be a direct correspondence between the points of the curve and the points of the surface.

Another approach is by "extruding" the curve in the `z` direction to form a cylindric surface, and intersect the cylindre with the surface. In this case, you form the system

```
S(x, y, z)= 0
C(x, y)= 0
```

where `z` is free, and solve for `(x, y)` as a function of `z`. (You can also use the parametric equations, there are different combinations.) In fact, you perform a parallel projection of the curve.

Instead of a cylindre, you can also think of a conic surface, by choosing a vertex point, say the origin, and considering the points `(zx, zy, az)` where `a` is an "aperture" coefficient and `z` is free. This idea is vey close to your "radius decrease" method and corresponds to a central projection.

Comment: I like the idea of extruding ! I will try this thank you for your answer !